# Glassfish JAX-RS serialising POJO to JSON fails

Tags: java, glassfish, jax-rs

I'm using Glassfish 4.1.2

I have a jax-rs endpoint that I want to return a JSON object serialised from my POJO entity.

The POJO:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class MyObj {

    public MyObj() {}

    private String value;

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

The resource:

```
@Path("/something")
public class MyResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public MyObj getMyObject() {
        MyObj myObj = new MyObj();
        myObj.setValue("Some Value");
        return myObj;
    }

}
```

Produces two exceptions, The first is thrown when the resource is first accessed after the server is started:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/parsers/ParserConfigurationException
```

All subsequent requests produce the exception:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.BeanValidationHelper
```

However, if I get the result as an XML (i.e. I change to `@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)`) it works without exception and the xml is returned no problems.

My request headers accept both xml and json.

**UPDATE**

My project's dependencies are:

```
javax:javaee-api:7.0
com.lambdaworks:scrypt:1.4.0
commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10
org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.6
```

I've basically stripped this project down to its bare bones.

**UPDATE 2**

Following advice from @peeskillet by adding `jersey.config.server.disableMoxyJson, true` to the Application properties map does kind of work:

```
@ApplicationPath("")
public class MyServer extends Application {

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> getProperties() {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("jersey.config.server.disableMoxyJson", true);
        return map;
    }

}
```

The initial request fails with:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/module/jaxb/JaxbAnnotationIntrospector
```

BUT then all subsequent requests do work and I can get the JSON in the respose.

I am a little concerned though that it initially fails.

Comment: What jars/dependencies are you using for your project?

Comment: @peeskillet see my update

Comment: What happens if you use Jackson, instead of the default MOXy for JSON processing? If you are using an `Application` subclass for your JAX-RS configuration, override [getProperties](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html#getProperties--) and add a property with key `"jersey.config.server.provider.classnames"` and value `"org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.JacksonFeature"`

Comment: You can also probably use key `"jersey.config.server.disableMoxyJson"` and `true` value.

Comment: @peeskillet please see my latest update

Comment: It's perculiar that the initial request gets a different response to the subsequent requests, it's as though the container hasn't initialised something which then gets initialised after (or during) the initial request. I'm guessing that glassfish is responsible, I'll look into changing the container to see if that makes a difference too.

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure what could be causing this. Looks like the server is having problem loading classes. The server (a brand new one) should already have all the jars needed, but for some reason it isn't able to load them. You can try Wildfly. If you use a container like tomcat, you will need to add all the jersey dependencies, as tomcat will not have a JAX-RS implementation.

Comment: @peeskillet I tried it with WildFly 10.1.0.Final (making no changes) and it works without any problems for both JSON and XML, in fact I was having a few other problems and changing to WildFly fixed those too, I guess Glassfish isn't as good as I had hoped. Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: I believe that this is to do with this bug in Moxy https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=463169

Comment: the issue with the missing Jackson jar is listed here https://github.com/javaee/glassfish/issues/21141

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't get this working correctly with Glassfish 4.1.2, I switched to using WildFly 10.1.0.Final and it worked right away.

**UPDATE**

Coming back to this I managed to get Glassfish working with Jackson.

It seems that `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/module/jaxb/JaxbAnnotationIntrospector` is because Glassfish 4.1.2 doesn't come bundled with a `jackson-module-jaxb-annotations.jar`.

The solution is to add the `jackson-module-jaxb-annotations.jar` to `<glassfish install>/glasfish4/glassfish/modules`

Then disable Moxy using:

@ApplicationPath("")

```
public class MyServer extends Application {

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> getProperties() {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("jersey.config.server.disableMoxyJson", true);
        return map;
    }

}
```